# Compile latex multiple times using python

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex

I'm compiling a latex document with python using the following code:

```
    from pdflatex import PDFLaTeX
    with open(f'{reportFile}', 'w') as f:
        f.write(template.render()
    pdfl = PDFLaTeX.from_texfile(reportFile)
    pdfl.add_args({'-output-directory': "/Users/username/Desktop/"})
    pdfl.create_pdf(keep_pdf_file = True, keep_log_file = False)
```

The code works fine, but the issue is that in order for my table of contents to be included in the latex document, I need to compile the latex file twice. How can I compile the latex file twice (or multiple times) using python? I've read other posts about compiling latex twice and using pdflatex in python, but can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use one of the existing tex automation tools like `latexmk`,  this will automatically compile the document the required number of times, do your bibliography etc. ...

Comment: Thanks, that worked well!